# How to identify if <some:element> is a tag handler or a component handler?

Tags: jsf, components, tag-handler

How to identify if `<some:element>` is a tag handler or a component handler during the development process (e.g. in Eclipse)? As of "Mastering JavaServer Faces 2.2" (Anghel Leonard) p. 538, `<ui:repeat>` is a component handler whereas `<ui:include>` is a tag handler. But during development I don't see any difference but the ignorance of that existing difference may lead to serious application errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> during the development process

The quickest way is to try setting the `rendered` attribute to `false`.

```xml
<ui:repeat ... rendered="false">
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

```xml
<ui:include ... rendered="false">
    ...
</ui:include>
```

If that works, i.e. the output suddenly disappears when refreshing the page in your favorite web browser, then it's an [`UIComponent`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uicomponent). If that doesn't work, then it's a [`TagHandler`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/view/facelets/taghandler).

This is because the `rendered` (and `binding` and `id`) attributes are only defined in the `UIComponent` superclass.